# Flutter: can't find dependency in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, package, dependencies, dart-null-safety

I want to migrate dart null safety but there is one package that isnt ready for null safety yet. When execute `flutter pub outdated --mode=null-safety` it get this:

```
Package Name             Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest

direct dependencies:
flutter_template_images  ✗4.0.0   ✗4.0.0      ✗4.0.0      ✗4.0.0

dev_dependencies: all support null safety.
You are already using the newest resolvable versions listed in the 'Resolvable' column.
```

The problem is the package `flutter_template_images` is not in my pubspec.yaml file so I cant delete it to migrate null safety.
I dont know where this package comes from and I want to delete it but how can I find and delete this package?

I appreciate every answer!

This is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5955

  pdf: ^3.3.0

  path_provider: ^2.0.2

  provider: ^6.0.0

  open_file: ^3.2.1

  intl: ^0.17.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
  printing: ^5.4.3
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.5
  firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
  fl_chart: ^0.36.3
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Hi! The [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_template_images) `flutter_template_images` is an internal dependency of Flutter. You can try to follow this guide: https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide maybe you can find the answer you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you, what does internal dependency mean? Is there a way to delete this package?

Comment: Flutter use this package when you run `flutter create` command. I don't think you can delete it

Comment: Can I migrate to null safety although I have this dependency that doesnt support null safety?

Answer (score 2):

There are few options:

- Have you tried `flutter clean`?
- Try deleting pubspec.lock file and run `flutter pub get`

[image]

Comment: Should I delete the file pubspec.yaml or just the code inside the file?

Comment: No don't delete `pubspec.yaml` file. Delete the `pubspec.lock` file. [@Dalon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16030430/dalon), I've updated my comment and added a picture for reference

Comment: I used the command '''dart pub remove flutter_template_images''' to remove the package :) But now I got a new problem, I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462644/null-safety-migration-error-package-has-unmigrated-dependencies-but-all-my-dep

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, couldn't find this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462644/null-safety-migration-error-package-has-unmigrated-dependencies-but-all-my-dep